# Вывести из списка в окно программы python Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter, button, radiobutton

Есть цикл, в котором создаются 3 радиокнопки, и заполняются в список. Как вывести эти кнопки из списка в окно программы ?
Вот код:

```
curRad = []
    for col in range(3):
        curRad.append(tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                     value=col, command=radCall))
        curRad.grid(column=col, row=1, sticky=tk.W)  # row=6
```

При попытке вывести через grid, ошибка : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'grid'. Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curRad = []
for col in range(3):
        curRad.append(tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                     value=col, command=radCall))
        curRad[col].grid(column=col, row=1, sticky=tk.W)  # row=6
```